# What am I doing wrong with range in conditional formatting in sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to figure out why my range doesn't work when adding a conditional formatting rule in Google Sheets. I only get the formatting to work in one single cell.

I want to change format on a row with multiple cells if the cell in column C (in that row) is ="Deleted". I use the conditional formatting rule Custom Formula. I write `=C11="Deleted"` and the range (under the header Apply to range) `A11:B11` or  `A11:B11, D11:K11` but it doesn't matter what I write, it only affects the first cell in the range (A11)

Why? What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to change the range and also tried to apply the formula in different rows and different sheet but I always get the same result...Only the first Cell in the Range is affected.

Custom formula is `=C11="Deleted"`
Range `A11:B11`

The formula works...I get the expected result but only affects the first cell in the range and not all the cells in the row that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "lock" the column in your formula, otherwise it shifts (interpreted as relative position) ==> `=$C11="Deleted"`

Comment: What is the easiest way to copy this formula to several rows? Now it works on one row.

Comment: Your "apply to" range should be `A11:B` or `A11:B,D11:K` so it keeps going after row 11 as long as it finds rows in those columns.

Comment: you're welcome, and likewise. Feel free to mark this topic as "resolved"/"answered" if you have no further question.